# Fetching data from Yahoo finance to Goole docs (Resource At Url Not Found)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[image: Fetching Yahoo finance data to Google sheet.]

Hello Everyone.

I was using transpose function to scrape a data from yahoo finance to google sheet.
It was working flawlessly until today morning and I am wondering what might have caused the problem here.

=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",N25,"/analysis?p=",N25,""""),"//tr"))

This was returning the data well but now it says Error : Resource at Url Not found.

Comment: As far as I know yahoo finance is generated by javascript and thus impossible to IMPORTXML

Comment: Well, It was working fine untill yesturday.